# text shows differently in emulator and android phone

Tags: android, android-layout

My widget program showing well in android emulator.  when i test with android phone (Samsung Galaxy Y Pro) shows text unreadable.  How can i solve this ? Also attaching main layout file

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/full_widget"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:background="@drawable/bkground"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_height="70dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/signal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/signal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:maxWidth="45dp"
    android:minHeight="70dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/network"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/signal"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Status1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/signal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/network"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="8dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Status2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/signal"
    android:layout_below="@id/Status1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="8dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Status3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/signal"
    android:layout_below="@id/Status2"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="8dp"
    android:textStyle="italic" /> 

   </RelativeLayout>
```

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by unreadable? Also, none of your textviews have any text in them

Comment: text appears are very small and text updated at run time

Comment: Textsize is set in sp, not dp. Try using that.

Comment: Edit **android:textSize="20dp"** OR Size as you need, property in needed TextViews.

Comment: @ChintanRaghwani In android emulator it looks fine with above layout

Comment: @ChintanRaghwani Is any need to customize for different screen resolutions ?

Comment: You can create different xml file for different Dvice Screen Size and can put in Drawable-ldpi/mdpi/hdpi.

Comment: See this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Happy to help. (By the way, 1 advice, if you like, then just add real location to your profile.)